# Overwrite Taxonomy Term page display settings with custom URL's

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, theming

I would like to define the display settings of my Taxonomy term page. As I understand, this is possible by configuring the Taxonomy view provided by the Taxonomy module.

However, I use custom URL's and by so, my taxonomy pages doesn't have the URL `taxonomy/term` but something like `products/tents`.
Is there a way to customize these pages with the provide view?

Comment: `taxonomy/term` is the _router_ path, `products/tents` is the _alias_. The path for your view should be the router path, i.e. `taxonomy/term/%`. No square brackets though, those are for tokens :)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, if you insert `taxonomy/term` in the path of your view, you should be able to style the term page of your taxonomy items? But if I enter a contextual filter, the results turn out to be empty... Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @Clive, the view only returns some results whenever I enter a number as contextual filter. If I enter a term like "tents", I don't get any results? It has been a while since I touch Drupal... :)

Comment: Ah ok, if memory serves you need to edit your contextual filter, specify validation criteria, and validate against the taxonomy term name rather than the id. Does that make sense?

Comment: More or less... I think I've got it working now but there seems to be another problem going on right now. Care for a chat? Or do I just create another question?

Comment: I'd ask another question to be honest, you'll get more eyes on it that way

Comment: Hoppa! Please convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the patterns used for Taxonomy URL aliases.

http://drupal.org/node/120631

Sounds like you want to use: [term:vocabulary]/[term:name]

If you have it enabled, you should be able to see the patterns here:
www.yoursite.com/admin/config/search/path/patterns

Comment: That's what I figured, but when I enter `[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]/%` in my path on the Views UI, nothing happens...

Answer (score 1):

First thing, For customize path you can use `Pathauto` module where you can provide customize path according to your requirements for Node, Taxonomy terms pages etc. Go to this path for customize paths : `admin/config/search/path/patterns`

Second thing, for customize `Taxonomy Term` pages you have to enable `Page Manager` which is available in `Ctools` module and then go to the admin/structure/pages and then enable the default `Taxonomy term template`. After enabling, click on edit. It will open a panel page. Then add the view that you want to show on this panel page.